# jpg file is not showing up in chrome

Tags: google-chrome, jpeg

I am having a problem in viewing a jpg file in chrome.

I have 4 pictures in a folder. All the browsers are showing up except my google chrome. Actually chrome shows only 3 pictures :( I am confused.

Can you check that in your chrome please? If your chrome does the same would you please help me to find out where is the issue?

```
No 1: <img src="http://demo.cutedrops.com/dmi/sites/default/files/donate-buttons/donate-my-insurance-ad-300-250.jpg" />
<br />
No 2: <img src="http://demo.cutedrops.com/dmi/sites/default/files/donate-buttons/donate-my-insurance-ad-200-200.jpg" />
<br />
No 3: <img src="http://demo.cutedrops.com/dmi/sites/default/files/donate-buttons/donate-my-insurance-ad-468-90.jpg" />
<br />
No 4: <img src="http://demo.cutedrops.com/dmi/sites/default/files/donate-buttons/donate-my-insurance-ad-125-125.jpg" />​
```

http://jsfiddle.net/h8KMP/

Note: I saved the file as "save for web" in photoshop cs6.

Thank you.

Comment: Wow. That *is* strange. It flickers once, then disappears from the DOM entirely...

Comment: With ***jsFiddles***, always hit the `RUN Button` after the page loads, no matter the fiddle. This will prevent flickers and other abnormalities after the page has loaded. Cheers!

Comment: Comment has been updated.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

AdBlock for Chrome may cause images to be blocked based on image dimensions.

If you are using this extension, try disabling it.

Comment: Awesome Andrey, Thanks a lot. Yes i disabled chrome facebook adblock. Now it is showing.

Answer (score 1):

I am using **`Google Chrome Version 23.0.1271.97 m`** and there are ***no issues*** with your `4` images.

Since Chrome does not have in-browser image info like Firefox does, I inspected the image in current version of Firefox via `Right-Click Mouse >>> View Image Info` and the image specs check out ok.

[image]

To verify the image itself is not the culprit, I downloaded it to a temp folder and checked out the specs using freeware [**IrfanView Image**](http://www.irfanview.com/) desktop application. The info validates well too, since IrfanView will detect any file-header issues if they exist.

[image]

**EDIT:**

A recent comment suggests the image disappears after it has been loaded. In that case I recommend that you check to insure your Chrome is updated to the current version.

From Chrome's settings, choose **`About Google Chrome`** to check if an update is available.

Comment: Thank you Arttronics, I really appreciate your help for taking your time to find out the issue. The problem was i have installed adblock extension.

Answer (score 1):

The issue I had was that Chrome wasn't showing jpeg files using sRGB color.  I just opened the image in Gimp and exported it out to jpeg to overwrite the original, and it worked!  I hope this helps someone out there.